# input check/uncheck all by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have write this code below, but i don't find the error.
When i click on "Check / Uncheck All" i want increase / decrease count on tag p result.
thanks

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function() {
  var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
  $(".chk2").prop("checked", status);
});


showChecked();

function showChecked() {
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length;
}
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=chk]").forEach(i => {
  i.onclick = function() {
    showChecked();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check / Uncheck All

<input type="checkbox" name="chk" class="chk" value="option1" /> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" class="chk" value="option2" /> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" class="chk" value="option3" /> Option 3

<p id="result"></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Paragraph should be closed with `</p>` (fixed in the Q. edit)

Comment: *"increase / decrease count"* - count of what exactly? Can you explain?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can solve your issue using below code where you can create one function to get the count of checked checkboxes, say `showChecked`. Attach click event handler for `checkAll` and for `chk` checkboxes.

`CheckAll` event handler can be used to check / uncheck all `chk` checkboxes as per current value of checkAll and call `showChecked` function to get count. In `chk` click handler, you can call function to get the count as well as check or uncheck `checkAll` as per total count of checked status of `chk` checkboxes

```js
$(function(){
$("#checkAll").on('click', function(){
  $(".chk").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
    showChecked();
});

$(".chk").on('change', function(){
    if($(".chk").length != $('.chk:checked').length){
       $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
    }
    showChecked();
});
});

function showChecked(){
 $("#result").html($('.chk:checked').length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check / Uncheck All

<input type="checkbox" name="chk" class="chk" value="option1" /> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" class="chk" value="option2" /> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" class="chk" value="option3" /> Option 3


<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on `"see below code whwere you can use jquery to solve your issue"`? *"See below code"* is obvious, *"you can use jquery to solve your issue"* I think OP already uses jQuery. Instead, try to explain in a paragraph and expand on your specific changes and improvement decisions. Also, a bit of code formatting would not hurt.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, thanks for comments. Initially i thought that code is self explanatory but i edited and added required comments. I said using jquery means you need not to use querySelector as jquery is enough but i might be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Below code will work if user select all checkboxs then check all-checkbox will be checked and if user unselect any one checkbox then check all-checkbox will be unchecked.

```js
$("#checkall").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    showChecked();
});
$(".cb-element").change(function () {
  if($(".cb-element").length==$(".cb-element:checked").length){
        $("#checkall").prop('checked', true);
        showChecked();
    }
  else{
        $("#checkall").prop('checked', false);
        showChecked();
    }
});
function showChecked(){
    $("#result").html($(".cb-element:checked").length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="checkall" />Check All</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: @luX, this answer is not showing count in result still you have accepted this which looks me little wrong :)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Your ans was incorrect cz even you checked all 3 check-boxes but it still shows first checkbox unchecked

Comment: I did not see that error. please take effort to show me